# Clean the Dust Outside of the Computer Casing

Tags: cleaning, maintenance

No, I am not referring to the [cleaning inside the casing](https://superuser.com/questions/775/how-do-i-clean-a-computer-from-dust); I want to know how to clear off the dust that gathers outside the computer casing, in the dark corners of the computer table, the forgotten space occupied by a byzantine of cables, that are unreachable by broom or vacuum cleaners.

I don't want to disassemble my computers and monitors and the wires connecting them just because i need to clear off the dust. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the same solutions from the [posts you referenced](https://superuser.com/questions/775/how-do-i-clean-a-computer-from-dust) would seem to equally apply to any *outside* portions of the computer:

- Compressed Air
- A Vacuum Nozzle or Brush (blowing or sucking)

Add to that: How about any sort of feather-style duster or just a cloth?

You may want to do this while your computer is off to prevent any knocked-loose dust bunnies from being sucked into your computer casing.

Comment: The compressed air would mostly result in moving only this dust in a wider space. Vacuum cleaner would match, but then be careful, because often little parts of i-dont-know-what fall in these places, and for sure they would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got given some [Cyber Clean Putty](http://www.thinkgeek.com/computing/accessories/b88d/) and have been using it to clean all sorts of stuff. My keyboard, mouse, phone, keys, edge of monitors etc etc.

Its really really effective and makes a big difference as you can squeeze it into all sorts of spaces. Comparible in price to something like a compressed air can, bearing in mind this stuff seems to last for quite a while.