# How should I investigate a slow computer which doesn't seem to use all available resources in the first place?

Tags: windows-7, performance

From time to time my this computer slows down a lot. This is particularly noticeable for Blender, a 3D software, where rendering times of a couple of minutes are multiplied by 7 or more. Relevant elements:

- Using W7 (latest updates), Lenovo W510 (latest UEFI/drivers).
- Fan blades are clean, no dust on vents.
- CPU temperature 50°C, frequency around 930 MHz, 58% of the base 1.6 GHz.
- GPU temperature 44°C, core frequency around 500 MHz, 135 MHz when idle.
- There is plenty of RAM, 50% still available.

I've read: [Computer is really slow](https://superuser.com/questions/45453/computer-is-really-slow). I made some measurements for two applications: Blender and FastStone Image Viewer. I started from a situation where the computer was slowww, and then just rebooted to restore the speed.

---

**Blender** (a CPU consuming application)

Resource monitor before and after an image rendering task is started. Orange is Blender activity:

[image] [image]

**Left** = Computer works normally -- **Right** = Computer is slow

When the system works normally, RealTemp reports the same value than Windows for CPU load (100%). When the system is slow, RealTemp reports only 29.6%. That's something I don't explain. Apart this, I don't see a significant difference between the two measures, at least a difference which can explain rendering time rising from 2 minutes up to 14.

**Question 1**: Does this difference between RealTemp and Resource monitor values indicate something that can help towards the solution?

---

**FastStone Image Viewer**

Looking at activity while using FastStone Image Viewer is also quite surprising. While FSIV struggled to display the first image, I queued next/previous image commands to keep the application busy for a longer time:

[image] [image]

**Left** = Computer works normally -- **Right** = Computer is slow

Again, while Windows reports 20% CPU utilization, RealTemp report 5%. But quite surprisingly, neither the CPU or the disk are actually overloaded while FSIV is unresponsive.

**Question 2**: How can I continue searching where is the bottleneck if CPU/Disk are not in the causes?

---

**Update**

It has been days without the problem, but it reappeared while at the same time I experienced 2 device manager errors "unknown device". The two devices:

1:
[image]

2:
[image]

I uninstalled the two devices, then scanned for device changes. It came back with a single error, with the same string: "pci\ven_8086 dev_3b64 subsys_215f17aa rev_06" for the device ID, but now the message is more clear:

[image]
(translates as *Simplified communication PCI controller*)

It seems related to [Intel ME](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005754/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html). I actually unistalled IME shortly before this problem occurred as I assumed IME was used only to support [Intel AMT, a remote management solution](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology_(AMT)) used in large companies (found on [vPro platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_vPro)) which I don't want.

- As a side comment I think letting someone manage a system remotely including when it is "powered off" is nothing but a [huge security risk](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/491375), not to say a plain view backdoor.

I'm reinstalling IME to see if this solves the problem in the long term. Will update this question later. Any further confirmation/objection between IME not installed and the symptoms I described earlier are welcome.

---

Sorry for the snapshots showing legends in French, this is hopefully easy to translate in English.

Comment: Make and model of your computer? One can assume that a Windows 7 computer is no less than 5 to 7 years old by now. Effectively at end of life and the reason it is “slow,” which is a relative term. Under the most optimal conditions this computer would probably be slow to me.

Comment: @Appleoddity: All information in the question, the problem of this old slow computer is that twice a day it is very fast.

Comment: Yes, I understand there is something slowing it down apart from how it should perform. But the computer being almost 9 years old is an important fact that shouldn’t be overlooked. It could be a number of things causing the issue. Have you run any hardware diagnostics? (HDD, RAM, Motherboard?)  it’s probably slow because of disk usage. That’s the most likely culprit when a computer slows down periodically. Especially with Windows 7 that is known to misbehave and consume nearly 100% of its resources at least twice a day doing windows updates scans. Resource monitor will help to identify that.