# Cleaning inside of computers (hardware)?

Tags: cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I clean dust from a computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/775/how-do-i-clean-dust-from-a-computer)

I didn't have any of the air pressure bottles  left when I last looked around. I have one of those silk (or something) cloths that are used to clean glasses and monitors. Is it a bad idea to use this? Not sure if its static.

What can I use that may be lying around the house to dust the inside of my computer?

Comment: Alot of these cloths use static to collect the dust, BE CAREFUL, ESD will wreck your pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a paintbrush with a wooden handle and *natural bristle* (NOT nylon) head to gently dislodge and brush away the dust - doing this outside is best. Don't even think about using a vacuum cleaner unless it is designed for electronic equipment.

Edit: Kyle is right - avoid those types of cloth.