# What's the best way to clean out dust from a laptop?

Tags: laptop, toshiba-laptop, cleaning

What's the best way to clean out dust from a laptop?

My laptop overheats due to the dust clogging up the heat sink inside.

Comment: Related (but not identical): [How do I clean dust from a computer?](https://superuser.com/q/775/358766)

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to do this.. either the delicate way or the quick way.

Delicate way .. strip the laptop down so that you can get to the veins in the heatsinks and either blow them out with compressed air or for the more stubborn bits, use a wooden toothpick.

Quick way .. If you have a compressor, take the battery out and blast air through every vent you can find.  Maybe take it down to a local garage and ask to use their air.  Just be aware that you can force dust into places where it wouldn't usually go with a mis-directed jet of high pressure air.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a can of compressed gas (available at most computer/stationary stores). You can find a lot more information in [this PC World article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/224328/how_to_clean_your_pc_inside_and_out.html), and I'm sure there are many others around the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Pressurised air can probably help. It's typically used to clean keyboards.

[image: Can of compressed air]

Answer (score 0):

**Use compressed air**  to blow out the dust. You may want to do this outside, since it can be a little messy. Keep your bursts short and gentle; anything stronger could push dust into even more difficult to remove places or at the worst  it could damage the fan or other internal components of your laptop.