# Laptop fan gets loud and shuts down computer then have Issues with programs

Tags: laptop, shutdown, fan, gaming, dell-inspiron

My laptop will rarely act up and shut down on its own. When it does, I boot it back up and once it boots, I have issues running things I ran just fine previously. Before the shut-down, I could run a certain game at 40-60 fps easily. After, it can't even run at an adequately playable framerate. It does this with all 3d games, and has major problems with particles in general as well. It's a dell inspiron 15 3000 series that used to be an 8.1 os, but now it's 10. Had this issue on both operating systems.

Anyone know what may be causing this?

Comment: Vacuum, compressed air. Clean it up. It's overheating clearly.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Do not, under any circumstances, use a vacuum cleaner on a computer! All that dirt whizzing past the nozzle and rubbing it back and forth on the carpet means that vacuum cleaner nozzles can carry a substantial static charge that can discharge into your electronics. But I agree with the diagnosis of overheating and the remedy of cleaning.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I do, all the time. And so do many people. At least all vacuum cleaners I've ever used will quite nicely discharge if I even touch the metallic pipe. But it is a good warning. Also I'm not suggesting shoving the vacuum cleaner inside a regular PC just like that. I don't know many good ways to really clean a case though, since few people would have a compressor with proper airflow to actually clear all dust out. Suggestions?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Ask for suggestions in a new question! :-) (If there' not already a question about it.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Alas, there is already http://superuser.com/questions/775/how-do-i-clean-dust-from-a-computer/4253

Answer (score 0):

Your system sounds like it's overheating. The fan is trying to compensate to remove excess heat away this causing it to go loud as it spins right up.

Like a PC it can get very dusty in there. Try opening it up and using compressed air or a vacuum remove dust inside and around fans. If you're adventurous type you could try replacing the thermal paste for the graphics unit and the processor. If you go down this route I usually use thermal paste by Artic silver.

Guide to applying could be found here:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rjF5jabXRCY